# jsPDF error on conversion

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

When I try to convert a html page to pdf with jsPDF it return a blank page and if I debug with firedebug that return a error

[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ossarotte/kaj2c9fz/11/#&togetherjs=5ygqiQfhOe)

> TypeError: headers[j] is undefined on jspdf.debug.js (linea 3329, col 5)
>
> rowData[headers[j].name] =tableRow.cells[j].textContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');

that is the html code of the page

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="logo"><img class="logoimg" src="images/logo_APRIE.png" alt="logo aprie"></td>
    <td colspan="3" class="verde altro">Questionario rivolto ai gestori di
        impianti di produzione di energia <br>alimentati con fonti
        rinnovabili, anche in modo non esclusivo
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="annorif"><b>Anno di riferimento:</b></td>
    <td class="giallo anno">2015</td>
    <td class="altro">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="altro"><b>I dati sono dovuti ai termini del comma 3 dell'art.
            7 della LEGGE PROVINCIALE 4 ottobre 2012, n. 20:</b><br> <br> <i>I
            soggetti pubblici e privati che esercitano sul territorio
            provinciale attività energetiche soggette a concessione,
            autorizzazione o altro titolo comunque denominato, o che realizzano
            progetti finanziati con contributi provinciali, devono fornire
            all'osservatorio provinciale dell'energia le informazioni, i dati e
            i documenti, se richiesti, per l'esercizio dei compiti e delle
            attività previste da questa legge.</i><br> <br> <b>e del punto 6
            della Delibera della Giunta Provinciale n. 1826 del 27 Ottobre 2014<br>
            <br> Per eventuali dubbi o chiarimenti si prega di contattare presso
            APRIE il dott. john doe (0123-456789 -
            john.doe@prova.it)
    </b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="altro"><b>Avvertenze:</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="altro">- il questionario è rivolto ai gestori di impianti di
        produzione di energia (inclusi gli impianti di teleriscaldamento) che
        utilizzano anche, o esclusivamente, fonti rinnovabili.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="altro">- nel caso una società gestisca più impianti o un
        sistema complesso composto da più reti</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="giallo altro"><b>- compilare solo le celle di colore
            giallo compatibili con la tipologia d'impianto</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="required altro"><b>- I campi con bordo di colore
                    blue sono obbligatorie</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

and the script for calling jspdf is

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var doc =  new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  var dochtml=$(\"#questionario\").html();
    $(dochtml).find(\"script\").remove();
  console.log (dochtml);
  // We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor

  // All units are in the set measurement for the document
  // This can be changed to \"pt\" (points), \"mm\" (Default), \"cm\", \"in\"
  doc.fromHTML(dochtml);
  doc.save('prova_quest.pdf');
});
</script>
```

Comment: `TypeError: headers[j] is undefined on jspdf.debug.js (linea 3329, col 5)`
`rowData[headers[j].name] = tableRow.cells[j].textContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');`

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ossarotte/kaj2c9fz/11/#&togetherjs=5ygqiQfhOe) jsfiddle with error